# Remove 'CMD+i' shortcut from Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut, vi

I am hoping to use `CMD+i` to replace `esc` in `vim` but found that `CMD+i` is mapped to `Show Inspector`. How do I remove this so that I can free up this shortcut in `vim`?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use `control [` instead of `esc`.

Answer (score 2):

[I just realised, this won't work for Esc, as it's not considered a valid modifier, but I'm posting it just in case it may help someone, somewhere...
Best guess is something like BetterTouchTool might be able to do it]]

You can do it in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts...

The trick is to first replace the command you **don't** want with junk, then add the one you **do** want..
...however, this method will only work if the function you require also has a menu entry.

example, using Terminal as I don't have vim...

first, replace your 'bad' command with junk

[image]

[image]

Then you're free to add your new command - if it exists as a menu item.