# How to force a service shortcut to override an application one?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app, services, omnifocus

I want to have a global "send to omnifocus" shortcut. I have enabled it and set via `Keyboard -> Services`.

Unfortunately, it seems to conflict with some default shortcut in the `Apple Mail`.

Is there a way to force services shortcut to be globally overriding applications shortcuts?

[image: OF3 keyboard shortcut setup]

Comment: Your second question deserves to be asked clearly. I’ve edited this so it’s about one practical problem. Feel free to ask again your second question. Might you add a screen shot of how you set up this shortcut - exact details matter to answer.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301231/remove-cmdi-shortcut-from-terminal/301232#301232 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223190/macbook-pro-yosemite-change-finder-shortcuts/223221#223221 Basically, you replace the conflicting shortcut with 'junk' so it frees up the key.

Comment: @Tetsujin And how do I find what is the offending/conflicting shortcut?

Comment: tbh, I don't know. That key combo [Cmd/Shift/O] does nothing in my Mail app.