# How to change or remove keybindings in Finder

Tags: finder, keybindings

The general shortcut to change window in a specific app is <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>’</kbd>.

This doesn't work in Finder where the same shortcut toggles visibility of status bar.

How to change this behavior of Finder?

Comment: It's not `Cmd  '` it's `Cmd  \`` & should work just the same in Finder as anywhere else. Toggle Status Bar is `Cmd /`

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe the problem is that I have an Italian localized OS with an Italian keyboard?

Comment: Yes, that had just occurred to me - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 although we don't have a definitive answer for italian, there's a general pattern for non-English keyboards. Maybe you could discern it from that.

Comment: I should add that I'm fine with `Cmd '`, I only would like to change or disable the shortcut connected to the toggle of status bar in Finder

Comment: Here's a QA showing how to replace an unwanted key command with 'junk' so you don't accidentally trigger it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301231/remove-cmdi-shortcut-from-terminal/301232#301232

Comment: @Tetsujin, thank you, I solved with this last suggestion